# unsure as to why the file errors out as syntax error

Tags: batch-file

```
set "us=no"
set "login="
set "ps=no"
set "password="
set "ns=no"
set "mn=no"
set "sc=no"
set "cl=no"
set "contact="

:st
cls
set "start=%CD%\bin\Skype\Skype.exe"
if "%us%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /username:%login%"
if "%ps"=="yes" set "start=%start% /password:%password%"
if "%ns%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /nosplash"
if "%mn%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /minimized"
if "%sc%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /secondary"
if "%cl%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /callto:%contact%"
echo "%start%"
pause
```

things ive tried:

removing the if portion on each line and trying the commands alone

removing the quotations (errors out)

putting quotations on both sides would save text" into "variable where the variable %variable"% would contain (text") im unsure as to why it keeps crashing with syntax error

specificly it errors out once it tries to add more text to start variable

btw. i need some setlocal enabledelayedexpansion too dont i? to process it as its read with !! yes?

Comment: Start two lines after `cls`. Add `::` at the start of every line down to the line right above `echo`. Save and try to run the file. Do you get the error? If so, what is the **exact** error message you get? If not, then remove the `::` from the line below that, save, and try to run again. Repeat until you know exactly which line is causing the problem and have an exact error message. Then come back and [edit] your post to include that information. *keeps crashing with a syntax error* is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if "%ps"=="yes" set "start=%start% /password:%password%"
    ^^^
```

should be

```
if "%ps%"=="yes" set "start=%start% /password:%password%"
    ^^^^
```

You knew that. Some times it just takes another set of eyes.